# Creating a Database Trigger that checks if more than one record was added on a date?

Tags: plsql, triggers

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER POSITION_NUMBER
BEFORE UPDATE OR INSERT OR DELETE ON APPLIES
  DECLARE
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
  NUMBER_OF_POSITIONS NUMBER;

  BEGIN

  SELECT count(pnumber) INTO NUMBER_OF_POSITIONS  
  FROM APPLIES WHERE anumber = :NEW.anumber;
  IF( NUMBER_OF_POSITIONS > 2 AND count(APPDATE) > 2 )
 THEN
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000,'an Employee cannot apply for 
  more than two positions');
   END IF;
   END;
  /
```

Im attemtping to create a trigger that goes off if an Applicant applys for more than two Positions on the Same Day, but im not sure how i would implement the Date side of it. Below is the set of relational Schemeas

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the TRUNC function to remove the time portion and then see if the application date matches today's date, regardless of time.

Also, there is no need for the autonomous transaction pragma. You are not executing any DML.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER position_number
   BEFORE UPDATE OR INSERT OR DELETE
   ON applies
DECLARE
   number_of_positions   NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT (pnumber)
     INTO number_of_positions
     FROM applies
    WHERE anumber = :new.anumber AND TRUNC (appdate) = TRUNC (SYSDATE);

   IF number_of_positions > 2
   THEN
      raise_application_error (
         -20000,
         'An Employee cannot apply for more than two positions on the same day');
   END IF;
END;
/
```